# Uploading large files not working on windows?

Tags: javascript, angular, linux, windows, file-upload

I am trying to upload the large file(let's consider Human Genome tar file, minimum 2.5gb) using Angular. If I upload it from Linux(in any browser, chrome or Firefox) it is working, But same file upload not working on windows (even chrome browser). Following is a service file,

```
import { HttpHeaders, HttpClient, HttpParams, HttpEventType } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class GenomeService {
    baseApiUrl = '###myapiurl###';
    public postGenome = (resrc: string, item: any): Observable<any> => {

        this.headers = this.headers.delete('Content-Type');
        return this._http.post(this.baseApiUrl + resrc + "/", item, {
            headers: this.headers,
            withCredentials: true,
            reportProgress: true,
            observe: 'events'
        }).pipe(
            map((event) => {
                switch (event.type) {
                    case HttpEventType.UploadProgress:
                        const progress = Math.round(100 * event.loaded / event.total);
                        return { status: 'progress', message: progress };
                    case HttpEventType.Response:
                        return event.body;
                    default:
                        return "Error......${event.type}";
                }
            }),
            finalize(() => {
                console.log("done");
            })
        );

    }

}
```

In the browser network tabit is showing as `net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`. I don't know, where I am making the mistake..?

Comment: In the component.ts file.

Comment: What kind of backend are you using? Any load balancer (like F5) or anything?

Answer (score 3):

Check ( on your backend' ssettings ) some parameter called maxRequestSize or maxRequestLength. It would have been easier if we know what kind of backend you're using. 
If it's DOT NET, it would be something like this :

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="xxx" />
```

set it depending to your needs

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `IIS` for hosting your application, then the default upload file size if `4MB`. To increase it, use this below section in your `web.config`.

***Note:*** `maxAllowedContentLength` is measured in `bytes` while `maxRequestLength` is measured in `kilobytes` which is why the values differ in this `config` example:

```
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <requestFiltering>
      <!-- For 50 MB set maxAllowedContentLength="52428800" -->
      <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="52428800" /> 
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
 
 <!--For 50 MB set maxRequestLength="51200"--> 
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="51200" executionTimeout="30" />
```

Comment: I tried with this kind of solution in linux config file but it is not working.. :-(